# Getting row number of text box clicked on

Tags: vba, excel

New to VBA and trying to create a pretty basic script however can't seem to find the answer on Google for what I am trying to do. In excel when you assign a macro to a text box, I want to be able to find the row that text box is in (aim is to insert a row above the text box which I can do).

So basically need to find the row of the text box that's been clicked on and is assigned to a macro.

Thanks,
Jacob

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why  it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time  to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers,  and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!  See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Application.Caller` to get the name of the shape, and you can go from there:

```
Sub insert_row()
Dim rec_name As String
Dim rw As Long
Dim shp As Shape

rec_name = Application.Caller
Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(rec_name)

Debug.Print shp.TopLeftCell.Row
rw = shp.TopLeftCell.Row

ActiveSheet.Cells(rw, 1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

End Sub
```

Assign that macro to the shape.

Comment: Thanks thats great! Looks really useful the application caller. I'm trying to learn VBA so will do some research on that.

Comment: @Jacob - Happy to help :D